# What is the difference between the following Neural Networks: Artifical NN, Static NN, Simulated NN

Tags: neural-network, terminology

I just came along the following names:

- Artificial Neural Network [1]
- Static Neural Network [1]
- Simulated Neural Network [2]

Do they all mean the same?

[1] Huang, B. and Kechadi, M.-T. An HMM-SNN Method for Online Handwriting Symbol Recognition. Image Analysis and Recognition, Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2006, 4142, 897-905.

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNN

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artificial Neural Network (ANN) seems to be the generic term. I guess people who use the prefix "simulated" only want to emphasize that it is not a biological neural network.

Every ANN is either "static" or "dynamic". Static ANN don't have context memory. Well-known types of ANN that are static are

- Multilayer Perceptron (MLP)
- Radial Basis Function Networks (RBFN)
- Wavelet Networks
- Fuzzy Networks

Well-known types of dynamic ANNs are:

- Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN)
- Time-Delay Neural Networks (TDNN)

See also: [Types of Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_artificial_neural_networks)

Comment: what is the benefits of having context memory or not?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. By context memory, do you mean the type of information which recurrent networks have?

Comment: i need to know why we need a context memory in the dynamic type?